# Change Range Of Displayed Pixel Values from Command Line?

Tags: image, matlab, processing

I'm working with some MRI data in Matlab 2014b, but the data is formed of intensity values not RGB. To get around this I use the code below to form a movie out of the MRI frames (I'm working on dynamic data here)

My problem is that the images need to have altered display values for the pixels, as the default only displays between -Inf and Inf, and I need between 0 and 0.25 to get a sensible image out of my data.

Are there any ways to pass that change from the script in to the movie, and then to write to file? I can only seem to do this per image in implay, and I'd like an automated way to edit each image and then store as a frame for a movie..?

```
%Code for producing movie.

graymap = gray(256);

for i = 1:32
    a(:,:,i) = cmunique(Reformed_Data_Colourmap(:,:,i));
end

for i = 1:32
    b = im2frame(a(:,:,i),graymap);

    a(:,:,1) = ((b.cdata));

    image(a(:,:,1))

    colormap 'gray'

%The change needs to be here, to display pixel values from 0 to 0.25, to allow for a sensible image from the MR data.

    frames(1,i) = getframe;

end

movie(frames)
```

Comment: You've lost me in your description - with still frames, movies and +/- infs. Can you take a step back and say what you start with (MRI data in some unclear format?) and what you want to end up with (a movie of something?)

Comment: Sure. 

I have a data set of 32 images which are all intensity data. 

If I were to use implay to view these, I need to change which pixel values are displayed from (-inf, inf) to (0, 0.25) to give a reasonable image. 

Is there a way of doing this from inside of a script, rather than using the tool box provided? 
The tool box method is of no use as I then want to store each of these images as frames, to make a movie.

Comment: Apologies, 

A colleague of mine has solved with clims. 

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided:

```
for i = 1:32

b = im2frame(a(:,:,i),graymap);
a(:,:,1) = ((b.cdata));

clims = [0 250];

%image(a(:,:,1),clims)
colormap 'gray'

imagesc(a(:,:,1),clims);

%set('window', [0 400])
frames(1,i) = getframe;
end
```

clims solves the issue.